# How to achieve Natural(human alpha-numeric ) Sorting, for silverlight datagrids using ViewModel?

Tags: mvvm, datagrid, silverlight-4.0, alphanumeric, natural-sort

In silverlight project that uses datagrid,  I am using some column that defines "Label number" which is a Varchar.

I want to sort this column as described in natural sort order as described in 
"http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting" or any possible way.

When I look around datagrid I saw SortMemberPath="stringProperty" only. Hence, my sorting is just working like string sorting only. For example:

Z1

Z10

Z2

Z20

where as I want it to sort like:

Z1

Z2

Z10

Z20

It will be of great help to have suggestion on this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Natural sorting of ObservableCollection<> ..., Compare each row of the Collection using class defined in link(http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/12/13/natural-sorting) and refresh the binding with datagrid. That worked.