# Silverlight Datagrid Numeric Sort

Tags: silverlight, sorting, datagrid, numeric

Is there simpler way to correctly sort numeric data in a datagrid?

Explanation - When you click on a column header with data 1,5,10,2 it sorts it as text (1,10,2,5).

I have read that you can implement ICollectionView, to create your own custom sorting. Before I go down that path, I want to make sure there isn't an easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A co-worker solved my problem.  By wrapping the source object in a wrapper, you can then define a SortBLANK, which just returns the data as int instead of string.  I then use SortMemberPath to set the sorting for that call.  Note, this only works for the problem of numeric only sorting.

XAML(Partial):

```
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="MAC" FontSize="12"  Binding="{Binding macaddr}" Width="100"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Upload Rate" SortMemberPath="SortUpload"  FontSize="12"  Binding="{Binding uploadRate}" Width="3*"/>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Download Rate" SortMemberPath="SortDownload" FontSize="12"  Binding="{Binding downloadRate}" Width="3*"/>
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Code-Behind(Partial):

```
public class OnlineDevicesWrapper
    {
        public string macaddr{get;set;}
        public string uploadRate { get; set; }
        public string downloadRate { get; set; }

        public int SortUpload
        {
            get
            {
                return int.Parse(uploadRate);
            }
        }

        public int SortDownload
        {
            get
            {
                return int.Parse(downloadRate);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a natural string sort comparer, using the IComparer interface.  There are several C# solutions out there, I've listed a few.  Note that I don't think any of them are geared towards Silverlight specifically, though you shouldn't have too much trouble using them in Silverlight.

[How to achieve Natural(human alpha-numeric ) Sorting, for silverlight datagrids using ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030761/how-to-achieve-naturalhuman-alpha-numeric-sorting-for-silverlight-datagrids-u)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/NaturalSortComparer.aspx

[Natural Sort Order in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx